# Search ElasticSearch via GET using JSON

Tags: json, http, search, get, elasticsearch

Anyone know of a way to send a JSON query to an ElasticSearch server via HTTP GET?  I know you can POST the JSON content to _search, but POST is not available because this is cross-domain.  For example, if my query looks like this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "fields": ["name", "description"],
            "query": "Elastic Search"
        }
    }
}
```

Which I would convert to something like:

```
{"query":{"query_string":{"fields":["name","description"],"query":"Elastic Search"}}}
```

Is there a way to **GET server:9200/index/type/_search?content=*stringifiedquery*** or something similar?  I've tried **q=** and **content=** as well as just passing the content after the **?** but nothing seems to work.  Anyone have any ideas?  Or am I just out of luck?

Comment: what language is initiating the request?

Comment: the language is likely to be javascript (with jquery) - it is really difficult to force jquery to send a GET request with a post body

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `source` query string parameter to send what would normally be the post body.

See the bottom of this page: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/

Comment: Will using source as the key value also work for POST requests? I ask because I'm trying to use RestKit (ObjC framework for json req/resp) and it tends to require key-value pairs for the json data (value) that is attached to the post request parameters being sent to the ElasticSearch instance.

Comment: This is awesome.  I notice that this parameter is not documented here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/search-uri-request.html Does anyone know if this is a deprecated feature that will eventually stop working in future releases?  It appears to be working as expected in ES 1.5.2.

Comment: @TonyCesaro it's small but it's there: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#_request_body_in_query_string